# Calculating the mean of part of an array

Tags: c, arrays, mean

I am trying to calculate the mean of high and low temperatures entered by a user and the number of days that can be included are between 1 and 4 however, I'm having difficulty understanding how to go about this. The code I wrote yields a completely irrelevant number. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int i;
    int limit;
    int day[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int high[10],low[10];

    printf("---===IPC Temperature Analyzer V2.0===---\n");

    printf("Please enter the number of days between 3 and 10, inclusive: ");
    scanf("%d", &limit);
    while (limit <= 2 || limit >= 11) {
        printf("Invalid entry, please enter a number between 3 and 10,   inclusive: ");
        scanf("%d", &limit);
    }

    for(i = 0;i < limit; i++) {
        printf("Day %d - High: ", day[i]);
        scanf("%d", &high[i]);
        printf("Day %d - Low: ", day[i]);
        scanf("%d", &low[i]);
    }

    printf("\nDay Hi Low\n");
    for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        printf("%d   %d    %d\n", day[i], high[i], low[i]);
    }

    int max = 0;
    int min = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        if (high[max] < high[i])
            max = i;
        if (low[min] < low[i])
            min = i;
    }

    printf("\nHighest temperature was: %d on day %d", high[max], day[max]);
    printf("\nLowest temperature was: %d on day %d ", low[min], day[min]);

    int n;
    int avg = high[i] + low[i]/i;

    printf("\nEnter a number between 1 and 4 to see the average temperature for the entered number of days, enter a negative number to exit\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    while (n > 4) {
        printf("Invalid entry, please enter a number between 1 and 4, inclusive: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }

    while (n < 0) {
        printf("Goodbye!\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf ("The average temperature up to day %d is: %d", day[i], avg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: THe only place you calculate `avg` is from `int avg = high[i] + low[i]/i;` You may want to think about what the value of `i` is at that point in your program. Nor does that number change during your last loop, so it is no wonder it is repeatedly reported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you misplaced expression `int avg = high[i] + low[i]/i`, and also the meaning does not seem correct to me:

First: I suppose you want to print the average for each particular day in the loop `i : 0..n-1`, but you calculate the value only once outside the loop (and you may think of what `i` at your place means.

Second: You have only two values for each day, i.e. high and low, and not `i` values, right? So to get the average temperature for a particular day it should be `avg = (high[i] + low[i])/2`. Also note the braces, which yields a different operator precedence than in your code. And if you want to calculate an "overal" avg up to a particular day, I'd make the formula explicit, e.g. by distinguishing an averageOfDay from an overallAverage.

Third: are you sure avg should be an int? I'd suggest to use float.

```
float avgSum = 0.0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    float avgOfDay = (high[i] + low[i])/2.0;
    avgSum += avgOfDay;
}
float overallAvg = avgSum/n;
printf ("The average temperature up to day %d is: %f", day[n-1], overallAvg);
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to get the average for a number of days between 1 - 4, so if the user enters say 3, it should calculate the average of high and low from day 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Ah, OK. I misinterpreted the fact that you print the "overal" average in a loop. See edited answer...

Comment: It's working now! However, the average for each day is appearing while I only want to output the last day. For instance if the user wants the average up to day 3 it will show the average up to day 1, the average up to day 2 and finally the average up to day 3.

Also would you mind explaining the += between avgSum and avgOfDay? I don't think I've ever seen it before.

Comment: Just put the calc and the printf outside the loop and use `n` instead of `i` (see adapted answer); Further operator `a += b` yields the same result as `a = a + b`; the operator is in use since the early beginnings of `c`, and you can also do `*=`, `-=`, ...